# Was Jeanne Dielman pregnant?

Tags: plot-explanation, jeanne-dielman

The movie "*[Jeanne Dielman, 23, Quai du Commerce 1080 Bruxelles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeanne_Dielman,_23_quai_du_Commerce,_1080_Bruxelles)*" directed by Chantal Akerman in the year 1975 deals with a widowed housewife who does her daily duties over a span of three days while making money through the job of a sex worker.

Hypothesis:

> Jeanne gets pregnant during the movie.

My reasons:

In the middle of the third act, which is the third and last day, a scene about the struggle of perfecting the taste of homemade coffee is being shown. After watching the scene, in which Jeanne Dielman fails to enjoy her coffee (which she usually likes), I came to the conclusion that she might be pregnant (the father could be one of her prior sex clients). A subsequent scene showing her playing with a baby she often babysits supports this interpretation, as earlier she didn't seem to care for the child's well-being during the second act. Even her daily house duties becoming sloppy on the third day supports the notion of change in her.

> Was Jeanne Dielman pregnant? Is there any confirmation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you asking whether Jeanne Dielman was pregnant, or are you telling us that she was pregnant?

Comment: @Community Thanks, I changed it and added my questions.

Comment: @F1Krazy I added my specific questions. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: ["Akerman has said in interviews that Jeanne had her first orgasm ever with her second client, the one that mussed her hair and caused her to burn the potatoes. She posits that for Jeanne, the lack of orgasm actually helped her maintain the order of her life."](https://blogs.iu.edu/aplaceforfilm/2016/11/30/jeanne-folds-the-meatloaf/)

Comment: FYI pregnancy doesn't suddenly change a woman overnight. Plenty of women don't even notice they're pregnant until weeks later.

Comment: @BCdotWEB But why does she have so maternal feelings for the baby and why does she not like the coffee?